# Error ENOENT no such file or directory ERROR An error occurred while running subprocess cordova

Tags: android, node.js, angular, cordova

I am trying to add android platform to my app, but it is giving me the following error. I had tried to resolve the errors by checking other posts on stack overflow, but I am still not getting it. I am new to Angular, so could someone help me out...

```
C:\Cordova_Practicals\battery-status-plugin>ionic cordova platform add android
> cordova.cmd platform add android
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Cordova_Practicals\battery-status-plugin\android\package.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Cordova_Practicals\\battery-status-plugin\\android/package.json'
}
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.
Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**This is my ionic info**

```
C:\Cordova_Practicals\battery-status-plugin>ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 
(C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 8.1.3
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete node-nodules folder, package-lock.json and run

```
npm install --force
```

in your project directory. Then try running your app.

Comment: I had tried that and still did not work. I created a new project yesterday, but that did not work. Today I did the same and ran it again. Now it is working properly. Thank you for replying.